# Wordpress query var 's' causes a 404 error when used on a page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Woocommerce site which uses special post statuses to display products which are no longer available for purchase. I have a page dedicated for that, but problems arise when I try to search on that page. Basically it means that the main query has both `s` and `pagename` set and Wordpress does not like that. It causes a 404 error. Also `post_type` may be present, it's value is `product`.

I can hack it by unsetting `s` in `pre_get_posts` but it has a drawback: subsequent processes, like Elementor's product grid, utilize `s`. The search function essentially does work, ie. appropriate products are fetched from the database, because the search phrase is read directly from `$_GET['s']`, which is bad and will probably not be like that forever. After unsetting `s`, the search field does not get populated, so that probably uses `get_query_var('s')` or something like that.

How do I prevent Wordpress from triggering the 404 process in specific cases, if both `s` and `pagename` are set in the main query?

Comment: So you used a normal, run-of-the-mill content page for that? Then WP _needs_ the `pagename` parameter, to be able to resolve the slug of that page to the post ID in the first place. If you combine that with a `s` parameter now, then it is of course likely not to find anything at all any more - because it would look for the keywords in the meta data of that particular page post now. Might make more sense to use the archive page for the post type for this somehow, or something like that.

Comment: Well, Woocommerce seems to do it that way. Woocommerce has a shop page, which is, as I understand, a page and not an archive. It does worl there.

Comment: But WooCommerce does its own query to display products AFAIK, that does not happen via the main query.